# Table row parents() not working

Tags: jquery

I have here nested table and delete animation. The `class="record"` delete perfectly but the `class="nested"` is not working. When I delete the record `class="record"` I also want to delete the `class="nested"` nested records. But why it's not working?

Here's my output. When I delete the counter 000007 the nested table should have delete animation also, but the record of 000007 only.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<table id="tfhover">

<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<tr class="record">
<td></td>
</tr>
// Nested Table

<tr>
<td>
<table id="loginTable">
<thead>
        <tr class="nested">
        <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

<tr class="nested">
<td></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table> // Nested table Close

</td></tr> // Nested table tr td Close

</tbody></table> // Main table Close
```

**FULL Delete Script**

```
<script>
$(function() {
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
//Save the link in a variable called element
var element = $(this);
//Find the id of the link that was clicked
var del_id = element.attr("name");
//Built a url to send
var info = 'name=' + del_id;
 if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
          {
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){
   }
 });

    $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
    .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow")
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: You do not have valid HTML: `</td></tr></tr>`. You should not have a `<tr>` directly inside another `<tr>`. You should fix that first.

Comment: @JohnS why it's not valid? But in my codes it works. The last <tr> is the closing of <tr> in <tbody> of main table

Comment: Tables rows simply cannot be nested like that. If you want the outer tbody to have two rows, you should move the second `</tr>` to just before the line with `// Nested Table`.

Comment: @JohnS Ok pardon me. Your right.

Comment: Please add to the question to show where the element represented by `$(this)` is located.

Comment: BTW - You still have an extra closing `</tr>` where you have `</td></tr></tr>`.

Comment: @JohnS I updated my question. And I include my full script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have valid HTML because you have a `<tr>` element nested directly inside another `<tr>` element. (Notice the line with `</td></tr></tr>`.)

Perhaps you want this:

```
<table id="tfhover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="record">
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="loginTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="nested">
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="nested">
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or this:

```
<table id="tfhover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="record">
            <td>
                <table id="loginTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="nested">
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="nested">
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

UPDATE:

Now that you have valid HTML, my best guess is you want:

```
$(this).closest(".record").animate({
    backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
}, "fast").animate({
    opacity: "hide"
}, "slow");

$(this).closest(".record").next().find(".nested").animate({
    backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
}, "fast").animate({
    opacity: "hide"
}, "slow");
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/532X7/)

Comment: your suggestion is working. Thanks. But how about my problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer with my best guess (without knowing more).

Comment: @jonh s Hello sir? Are you there?

Comment: @user3097736 - Did that help? I'm here now for a few minutes.

Comment: it helps, Just want to change something in your codes. I want to do the animation in TR of Nested table. // Nested Table <tr> . I tried to change the class name but it not work. Please help me

Comment: @user3097736 - I don't understand because the "nested" class is on the `<tr>` elements of the nested table, so it should be the `<tr>` elements that are animated.

Comment: I need to do the erased animation to the <tr> of nested table. Just like in your example html. The Tr after the closing tr of class="record"

Comment: that Tr holds the nested table. So that tr should erased also after deleting record in main table

Comment: @user3097736 - In case there isn't always such a row, it would be safest to add a class to that row. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/532X7/1/).